# What is the "u=" and "i=" class in CSS?

Tags: 7, theming

I am trying to modify the CSS in a Drupal 7 theme from being statically coded to one which is generated by views.  The person before me, wrote the slideshow directly into the page--front.tpl.php file and this makes it next to impossible for users to change the slideshow without getting a Drupal developer involved.

In the "static" page, there are some tags which, due to my ignorance, I don't know how to deal with.  For exampe:

```
<div id="yourid" class="yourclass" u="slides" ...>
```

I know what the "id" is and I know what the "class" is, but I have no idea what the "u=" references.  I have also seen:

```
<div id="yourid" class="yourclass" i="icons" ...>
```

Can someone tell me the terminology associated with this tag so I can research it?  Typing in `"<div u="` in Google is bringing up tons of unrelated results

Comment: You shouldn't need to work with the 'u' and 'i' attributes when writing CSS

Comment: Excellent @Cilive  Something I run across in DRUPAL, while trying to THEME in CSS for which I say I don't have the correct terminology is for you to be ever so helpful and say "Off Topic, go somewhere else."  If this is off topic, why have those tags?  If you are so knowledgeable, why not a point in the right direction?

Comment: You can run across a picture of a cat in Drupal, does that mean you should be able to ask a question on identifying it here too? You're asking for someone to identify the meaning of HTML attributes - whether they are standard are non-standard, that doesn't have anything to do with Drupal. Someone's already given you a response, so you have an answer, the question is fundamentally off-topic, and now it's closed, per the way every Q+A site in this network operates. What "point in the right direction" do you feel I could give you here? The closure has been explained, and your question answered

Comment: Even better.  Not only are you not helpful, but insulting to boot.  Did I ask about content or something I din't know was/wasn't specific to Drupal theming conventions?  Please don't try to defend your obstructionist answer as following policy - if you KNEW what an answer was, why not say it AND THEN point me to the right forum?  Too "end user helpful centric" for you?

Comment: @Clive is correct: `<div id="yourid" class="yourclass" u="slides">` is just an HTML tag with non standard attributes. There is nothing in it that is Drupal specific, which means a Drupal standard installation doesn't output anything like that. You are asking about the meaning of those attributes, and for Drupal they don't have any meaning.

Comment: If you were asking which module outputs those attributes, then the question could be more on-topic, but unfortunately we cannot look for every existing module to tell you which module outputs that. Since you have access to the site you are developing, you would have more chances than us to find which module would output that; we don't have access to any sites you are developing, so we should work hard to find that module, or be very lucky to guess it.

Comment: That's not the point.  My point is Cilive could have stated your first sentence exactly which would have explained why it's off topic as opposed to the the curt approach he decided to take.  I am not saying the answer is wrong, I am saying his approach to the answer is wrong.  It is not helpful and obstructionist followed by a condescending, sarcastic response.  It was in page--front.tpl.php and not a module (see OP)

Comment: @Allan Chill out, the only sarcasm in this comment thread has been from you (read it back if you don't believe me, it's all still there). There hasn't even been a hint of an insult from anyone, not sure what you're talking about there. It isn't my fault you didn't know this was a plain-HTML, and not Drupal, question. No one's blaming you for that, we all learn as we go, but given that you'd already received and acknowledged an answer as correct, and the question is fundamentally off topic, I don't understand what your issue with it being closed is, or what message you expected from me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those attributes ("u" and "i") are not standard attributes. They seems from this [JOSS slider](http://www.jssor.com/) or another slider.

Examine your Drupal modules and the View your want to modify to know which slider are you using. Then check the documentation for that slider.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for "they are not standard attributes." Now I know how to approach and what I need to do in views. And yes...it appears it is JOSS slider"